# rewrite url not working on ubuntu localhost in php

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the file called call_center_interface.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule call_center_interface-act-(.*)\.htm$ call_center_interface.php?act=$1
```

i use the above url rewrite code but it is not working in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the mod_rewrite module in apache? Run it as root or use sudo:

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

There is any other rewrite rule that is working?

Comment: Run it as root, or use sudo: `$ sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Hi Donny, to make things more clear I edited my answer with your complementary info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to place your code between

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
</IfModule>
```

otherwise on some servers you'll run into a 500-Server-Error-Page.

If you add a RewriteBase statement with the directory or subdirectory below your document root, you're also more safe (say: /var/www/foo/scripts/call_... and /var/www/foo is your document root, add 'RewriteBase "/scripts/"'.